# Using から (because) with nouns, adjectives and verbs

Tags: grammar

Could someone please check my understanding of how から is used with nouns etc?

Today I read what I think were some rules. から needs だ/です depending on what precedes it.

> しずか　ですから　散歩しましょう

-na adj, needs です.

> 天気がいいから　散歩しましょう

-i adj, doesn't need です

> コーヒーを飲むことですから、しずかにしてくれ

noun, needs です.

> 猫がいますから、しずかに　してくれ

verb, doesn't need です

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have the right idea- nouns and na-adjectives require a copula (だ・です) before it. That way, it doesn't get mixed up between the "from" meaning of から.

> しずか　ですから　散歩しましょう

Correct; a copula is required if a na-adjective comes before から.

But I do want to point out that you *can* still use だから (as opposed to ですから) even if the sentence is polite. The most important thing is that the main (i.e. final) verb is in the polite form.

> 天気がいいから　散歩しましょう

Correct; with い adjectives using だから is ungrammatical. (You actually *can* use ですから with an い adjective, but it isn't necessary.)

> コーヒーを飲むことですから、しずかにしてくれ

You are correct that you'll need だから or ですから after the noun こと. But I don't see any reason to have こと there at all. It should just be 飲むから (or, in this case, 飲んでいるから).

Also, the inconsistency in politeness here is a little strange. You used impolite -てくれ at the end, but polite ですから in the middle. It is weird to have an impolite independent clause with a polite dependent clause. But that's not what this question is about.

> 猫がいますから、しずかに　してくれ

Correct; だ or です do not (and cannot) immediately precede から if there is a verb and not a noun or na-adjective there. (However, this sentence also has the same problem as last time with the inconsistent politeness)

Comment: What is the meaning of しずかにしてくれ? " is it the same with しずかにしてください (please be quiet)? But it doesn't seems to fit (not make sense) in the sentence samples of cat and coffee.

Comment: maybe it's a big cat and if you're not quiet and wake it then .... well let's just say you've got bigger problems.

Comment: なぜあの人が好きですか。あの人はきれい(だ/です）からです。I feel a bit strange to hear きれいだからです。 or きれいですからです。What do you think?

Comment: @優しいエイリアン those do sound weird; I think you'd just use だから or ですから instead.